# How to get init parameter of servlet at web.xml from jsp?

Tags: jsp

web.xml is

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>heading</param-name>
        <param-value>This is heading</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>.
```

How can I get init parameter "heading" from jsp page?

Answer (score 7):

```
<%=config.getInitParameter("heading")%>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Got it!
My servlet mapping is wrong!
The correct mapping is...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>heading</param-name>
        <param-value>This is heading</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now, we can access init parameter by "<%=config.getInitParameter("heading")%>" or "<%=getInitParameter("heading")%>".

Thanks Peter Rader.